# How to repeat colours as a cycle in ggplot with scale_fill_viridis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Since I have a lot of metabolites that I am showing in my proportion stacked barplot, this means when I use scale_fill_viridis, it is very hard to distinguish some of the colours from metabolites that appear consecutively (see image). Is there a way I can just repeat the colours, say take 6 unique colours from the viridis library and just cycle it. The legend would be in order of the metabolite appearance in the graph, so cycling the colours would still be easy to interpret following the legend order.

[image]

I don't have a way to show you my outcome other than have a cycle of the same colours, so something like:

```
Ala = dark purple
allo.ille = purple
Ans = blue
Arg = green
Asp = light green
Car = yellow
```

And then, cycle those colours for the next 6 metabolites in order:

```
Citr = dark purple
Cys = purple
Cyst.1 = blue
Cyst.2 = green
Eth = light green
GABA = yellow
```

Here is the code I used to make my graph (commented out are the other scale fills I tried using but they don't seem to work at all) and I need help tweaking scale_fill_viridis, or I am also open to other palettes or ways to introduce a cycle of colours rather than a gradient:

```
library(viridis)
library(ggplot2)

# From suggestion below, did not work
#color_mapping <- rep(viridis(6),100)

ggplot(df, aes(fill=group, y=value, x=Species)) +
geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity") + 
#scale_color_manual(values=color_mapping[1:n_distinct(df$group)])+
#scale_colour_brewer(palette="Set5") + 
scale_fill_viridis(discrete=TRUE, name="NEFA Content") +
theme_ipsum() + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=1,vjust=0.25)) +
theme(axis.title.x=element_blank()) + theme(axis.title.y=element_blank()) +
theme(panel.background=element_rect(colour="black")) +
theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank())
```

Comment: Could you please provide `dput(df)`.

Answer (score 1):

I have a dirty solve for this, not really a fan of it (maybe my colour choices are bad) but I did manage to get the cycle of colours I wanted. What's important was listing the colours out and repeating them and making sure they exactly matched the number of metabolites or categories I had.

Here is the code and here is the output. I repeated 6 colours I from the viridis package 7 times because I had 42 metabolites I was showing on my figure.

```
ggplot(df, aes(fill=group, y=value, x=Species)) + 
  geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity") + 
  theme_ipsum() + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=1,vjust=0.25)) +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank()) + theme(axis.title.y=element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.background=element_rect(colour="black")) +
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank()) + scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#440154FF", "#3F4788FF", "#2D718EFF", "#29AF7FFF", "#94D840FF", "#FDE725FF",
                                         "#440154FF", "#3F4788FF", "#2D718EFF", "#29AF7FFF", "#94D840FF", "#FDE725FF",
                                         "#440154FF", "#3F4788FF", "#2D718EFF", "#29AF7FFF", "#94D840FF", "#FDE725FF",
                                         "#440154FF", "#3F4788FF", "#2D718EFF", "#29AF7FFF", "#94D840FF", "#FDE725FF",
                                         "#440154FF", "#3F4788FF", "#2D718EFF", "#29AF7FFF", "#94D840FF", "#FDE725FF",
                                         "#440154FF", "#3F4788FF", "#2D718EFF", "#29AF7FFF", "#94D840FF", "#FDE725FF",
                                         "#440154FF", "#3F4788FF", "#2D718EFF", "#29AF7FFF", "#94D840FF", "#FDE725FF"))
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Or even just use color_mapping=rep(c(""#440154FF", "#3F4788FF", "#2D718EFF", "#29AF7FFF", "#94D840FF", "#FDE725FF"),7) and then call scale_fill_manual(values=color_mapping)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the viridis colors to a vector and use that to manually color your plot:

```r
# this is just because I was to lazy to count how many values you actually need. When calling ggplot, it will only select as many colors as it actually needs "[1:n_distinct(dsamp$clarity)]" part later
color_mapping <- rep(viridis(3),1000)
dsamp <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
ggplot(dsamp , aes(carat, price)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = clarity)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = color_mapping [1:n_distinct(dsamp$clarity)])
```

With you code it should look something like this:

```r
library(viridis)
library(ggplot2)
color_mapping <- rep(viridis(6),1000)

ggplot(df, aes(fill=group, y=value, x=Species)) +
  geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=color_mapping[1:n_distinct(df$group)]) +
  theme_ipsum() + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=1,vjust=0.25)) +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank()) + theme(axis.title.y=element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.background=element_rect(colour="black")) +
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank())
```

Comment: It still produced a gradient for me, just the colour scheme is different even though we're calling viridis.

Comment: Actually no matter what I do, even using scale_color_brewer it is giving me the same colour scheme. I can't seem to get any other colour scheme except with scale_fill_viridis and it's a gradient I don't want.